# Unreal Engine FDirectoryWatcherModule catching multiple events per file operation

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit, unreal

I followed [this](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/how-to-trigger-an-event-when-a-file-changes-and-get-the-path-to-this-file/145224/2) post to implement a delegate on a directory that notifies me when a change has happened (add file, delete file or remove file).

This works fine, though the issue is that for each operation, multiple events are triggered. In the `Data` array containing information from the operation, I see the following behaviour:

- When adding an image, `Data` size is 5 and contains one `FCA_Added` and 4 `FCA_Modified`.
- When deleting an image, `Data` size is 1 and contains a FCA_Removed.
- When adding multiple images (for example 2 images), `Data` size is 10 and contains one `FCA_Added` and 4 `FCA_Modified` for the first image and one `FCA_Added` and 4 `FCA_Modified` for the second image.

Note: Sometimes adding an image will result in fewer `FCA_Modified`. For example, in another PC, each image results in one `FCA_Added` and two (rather than four) `FCA_Modified`.

In any case, the issue remains that `Data` is providing a large number of events for each operation. If I want to control this with a switch for example, it means each image will trigger my `UpdateDynamicMaterialArray` multiple times when only one call is required per file.

I attached an image with the console output for a 2 file addition operation.
[image]

Edit: To clarify the console output image, Element action **1** is a `FCA_Added` and an Element action **2** is an `FCA_Modified`.

The function I use to control the events:

```
/**
 * Will trigger when a change (addition, replacement, deletion) is performed on ResourcesDirPath
 * @param Data Array of type FFileChangeData indicating the nature of the change observed
 */
void AMyController::OnProjectDirectoryChanged(const TArray<FFileChangeData>& Data) {
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Data num: %d"), Data.Num());
    for (FFileChangeData Element : Data) {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Element filename: %s"), *Element.Filename);
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Element action: %d"), Element.Action);
        switch (Element.Action) {
            case FFileChangeData::FCA_Added:
                UpdateDynamicMaterialArray(&Element.Filename, FFileChangeData::FCA_Added);
                //MyReferenceManager->MyHUD->AddTile();
                break;
            case FFileChangeData::FCA_Modified:
                UpdateDynamicMaterialArray(&Element.Filename, FFileChangeData::FCA_Modified);
                //MyReferenceManager->MyHUD->RefreshTile();
                break;
            case FFileChangeData::FCA_Removed:
                UpdateDynamicMaterialArray(&Element.Filename, FFileChangeData::FCA_Removed);
                //MyReferenceManager->MyHUD->RemoveTile();
                break;
            default: ;
        }
    }
}
```

[FFileChangeData](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/API/Developer/DirectoryWatcher/FFileChangeData/) docs and [EFileChangeAction](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/API/Developer/DirectoryWatcher/FFileChangeData/EFileChangeAction/) did not help.

Why does one operation result in multiple events of different type? I suspect this is OS related (I use Windows) and that there is not much I can do. Is this true?